# Logging client run times to server log file using AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, logging

So I have to log client-side script run times to a server side log file.  I measure the time the function takes, and then I report it to the server via ajax.  Does this code look correct?  I don't have access to production server right now, XAMPP is malfunctioning, and I don't want to show this to my boss until I'm sure it'll work.  This is my first time using AJAX, and my second time using JS.

in my index.php:

```
function search(x,acc)
    {
           var startTime = new Date().getTime();
           //do work
           //
           var endTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
           var outputMessage = "The process took: " + max/1000 + "seconds";
           console.log(outputMessage);
           $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "ajaxCallback.php",
           data: {outputMessage},
           success: function()
                    {
                        console.log("Client Side : Ajax post     submitted.");
                    }
            }
    }
```

Then ajaxCallback.php:

```
<?php
    $stringData = $_POST['outputMessage']; 
    echo $stringData;
    $myFile = "logFile.log";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: This is not the place to ask codereview questions... That is for [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `data` param in your `ajax` call needs to use a `key/value` pair:

```
data: {outputMessage:outputMessage}
```

in your `outputMessage`, the variable `max` is not defined.

Also proper error handling should be considered when using `fopen`:

```
if($fh = fopen($myFile, 'a')){
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);    
}else{
    die("can't open file");
}
```

Everything else looks pretty straight forward.